# Set number of columns and rows with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gdalwarp

I know how to resample a raster using pyQGIS 3.0 and the gdal warptranslate function by imposing the pixel dimension of the output file, see below.

```
rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer('/path/inputfile.tif', 'raster')
    
parameters = {
    'INPUT': rasterLayer,
    'SOURCE_SRS': "EPSG:32632",
    'TARGET_SRS': "EPSG:32632",
    'RESAMPLING': 1,
    'NODATA': 0,
    'TARGET_RESOLUTION': 30,
    'OPTIONS': "",
    'DATA_TYPE': 6,
    'TARGET_EXTENT': rasterLayer,
    'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS': "EPSG:32632",
    'MULTITREADING': True,
    'EXTRA': "",
    'OUTPUT': "/path/fileout.tif"}

processing.run('gdal:warpreproject', parameters)
```

Is there a way to resample a raster by imposing instead the number of columns and rows (pixel dimension can varies)?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate target resolution from the layer extent and number of columns/rows.

```
rows = 1000    # set as you need
cols = 2000    # set as you need

rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer('/path/inputfile.tif', 'raster')
ext = rasterLayer.extent()
x_res = (ext.xMaximum() - ext.xMinimum()) / rows
y_res = (ext.yMaximum() - ext.yMinimum()) / cols
res = min(x_res, y_res) # or max or mean?
```

Then add resolution to processing parameters. As far as I know you cannot set different resolutions in x and y directions from processing (while in the command line version of gdalwarp it is possible).

Comment: Hi Zoltan. Unfortunatelly I think you provided the right answer, I mean, if you were using gdalwarp from the command line you could decide the number of rows and columns adding  -ts width height. There is a method in gdal:warpreproject calle "EXTRA". I was wondering wether it is possible to use it to set columns & rows

Comment: I've got it: just add this statement to the "extra" parameter  'EXTRA': "-ts {width height}", and remember to leave blank the target resolution, so  'TARGET_RESOLUTION': "",